# condicion para obtener url con diferentes datos. en un metodo get. java

Tags: java

necesito realizar una condición para cuando el STRING moreparams viene vació quitar 2 parametros .append(&) y el .append(moreParams). que no lo muestre en la url. en caso que si tenga, mantenga esos .append

tenia pensado dos condiciones 1 si viene null el more params sacar los párametros y sino dejarlos

pero no me estaría funcionando. si necesitan mas información avísenme gracias.

ejemplo la url = https://hotel.google.net/hotels/ytd.proba.miami,2/MIA/XXXXX-XXXXX/1DR;1DR;?token=Ws2QmzjsxDFC7jeN&RDI=hhdwjsj2232542bhdwhdwdkmkdmwd.

los casos serian quitar & y moreparams que es RDI= cuando viene vacio el moreParams

```
public String get(String request, String uri, String moreParams) throws Exception {
        startTimer();
        StringBuilder requestUrl = new StringBuilder();

        if (moreParams == null)
        requestUrl
                .append(url)
                .append(uri)
                .append("/")
                .append(contractName)
                .append(",")
                .append(agencyNumber)
                .append(request)
                .append("?token=")
                .append(token);

        else
            requestUrl
                    .append(url)
                    .append(uri)
                    .append("/")
                    .append(contractName)
                    .append(",")
                    .append(agencyNumber)
                    .append(request)
                    .append("?token=")
                    .append(token)
                    .append("&")
                    .append(moreParams);


        logger.trace("URL={}", requestUrl.toString());
```

Comment: ¿Con vacíos te refieres a que en el método te lo pasen null o también incluyes la cadena vacía “”?

Comment: Solo ese string, moreParams. si ese viene null  que saque el & ,si vienen datos en moreparams que deje el & y el moreparams. pero si seria lo primeron si me lo pasan null, quitar esos 2 de la url

Comment: No se bien lo que quieres, pero prueba poner en el condicional `moreParams == null || moreParams.isEmpty()`. Creo que estás confundido. Piensas que `null` es lo mismo que el string vacío (`""`), y no es lo mismo. De manera alternativa, si quieres desechar cadenas con puros espacios en blanco, la condición sería `moreParams == null || moreParams.trim().isEmpty()`. Por si no queda claro, cuando digo "la condición" me refiero a lo que va dentro del paréntesis del `if`.

Comment: exactamente esoo. si me exprese mal perdón. ahi realice esa condición que me pasaste con moreParams == null || moreParams.trim().isEmpty(), y me funciona perfecto muchísimas gracias.